# idele and norm residue symbol

Tags: number-theory, adeles

Let $M=F_{ab}$ the maximal abelian  extension of $F$. His Galois group is profinite. If $K$ is a  finite abelian subextension, the Artin map gives a surjective morphism
$C_F\longrightarrow Gal(K/F)$
from idelic class group of $F$ on Galois group.
taking projective limit we construct a morphism  from $C_F$ in $Gal(F_{ab}/F)$.
It's the  definition given by N. Childress in her Class Field Th of the norm residue symbol.
I do not see why is it onto and continuous.

If i try to write a bit what happen, on my right i have a compatible collection of automorphismes  of abelian sub-extension $(\sigma_K)$. By "compatible" i mean

if $K_1\subset K_2$ then $\sigma_{K_2}\mid_{K_1}=\sigma_{K_1}$

By surjectivity $\forall K, \exists c_K\in C_F,$   such that $\sigma_K={\cal A}_K(c_K)$

where ${\cal A}_K$ is the Artin map defined on idèles $J_F$ or class-group $C_F$.

Compatibility just said
if $K\subset L$, ${\cal A}_K(c_K)={\cal A}_K(c_L)$

and i do not see how to obtain a unique class especially since $C_F$ is not compact.